# Import navigation icon without padding

Tags: android, android-studio, android-assets

I'm struggling with importing png files into my Android Studio project. The Asset Studio adds a margin around the png and there doesn't seem to be any way to disable this.

Example:
[image]

What I would like is the asset to be just like 'Source Asset' with the left and right sides being right up against the edges, but instead it ends up like this:

[image]

Can it really be true that there is no way of doing this?

Comment: try giving negative padding to your icon

Comment: Hi Vivek. That doesn't work, it just crops the image but keeps the margin.